Postgresql connections get disconnected after 5 minutes of being idle
We are connecting to a database without any connection pooling. We noticed that the session disconnects everytime after around 5 minutes (+or- 3~4 seconds)
Disconnection log from the alert log :
2024-11-11 17:51:28.627 UTC,"test30","test30",479460,"172.16.83.81:1083",673242f0.750e4,4,"idle",2024-11-11 17:46:24 UTC,7/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"psql","client backend",,0
2024-11-11 17:51:28.627 UTC,"test30","test30",479460,"172.16.83.81:1083",673242f0.750e4,5,"idle",2024-11-11 17:46:24 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"disconnection: session time: 0:05:04.424 user=test30 database=test30 host=172.16.83.81 port=1083",,,,,,,,,"psql","client backend",,0

024-11-11 18:00:16.890 UTC,"test30","test30",483965,"10.22.84.0:39903",67324501.7627d,4,"idle",2024-11-11 17:55:13 UTC,7/0,0,LOG,08006,"could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer",,,,,,,,,"psql","client backend",,0
2024-11-11 18:00:16.890 UTC,"test30","test30",483965,"10.22.84.0:39903",67324501.7627d,5,"idle",2024-11-11 17:55:13 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"disconnection: session time: 0:05:03.791 user=test30 database=test30 host=10.22.84.0 port=39903",,,,,,,,,"psql","client backend",,0

Here are the timeout settings :
postgres=# select name,setting,context from pg_settings where name like '%timeout%';
                name                 | setting |  context
-------------------------------------+---------+-----------
 archive_timeout                     | 1800    | sighup
 authentication_timeout              | 60      | sighup
 checkpoint_timeout                  | 300     | sighup
 deadlock_timeout                    | 1000    | superuser
 idle_in_transaction_session_timeout | 0       | user
 idle_session_timeout                | 0       | user
 lock_timeout                        | 0       | user
 statement_timeout                   | 0       | user
 tcp_user_timeout                    | 0       | user
 wal_receiver_timeout                | 60000   | sighup
 wal_sender_timeout                  | 60000   | user
(11 rows)

At the OS level on the DB server, there are some netfilter parameters set :
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets = 262144
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_checksum = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_loose = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_closereq = 64
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_closing = 64
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_open = 43200
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_partopen = 480
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_request = 240
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_respond = 480
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_dccp_timeout_timewait = 240
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events = 2
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_expect_max = 4096
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_frag6_high_thresh = 4194304
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_frag6_low_thresh = 3145728
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_frag6_timeout = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_gre_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_gre_timeout_stream = 180
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmpv6_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_log_invalid = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 524288
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_closed = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_cookie_echoed = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_cookie_wait = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_established = 210
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_heartbeat_sent = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_shutdown_ack_sent = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_shutdown_recd = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_sctp_timeout_shutdown_sent = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_ignore_invalid_rst = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose = 1
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_timestamp = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 120

I did some tinkering around and found that when my Postgres parameter "tcp_keepalives_idle" is < or =285, the connection remains intact. When it is >=286, the connections gets disconnected in 5 mins.
What particular parameter above could be causing this issue?
Or is it something totally different?
Some of my suspects are :

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 300 (The 300 second value makes it suspicious but since the connection is already established, I don't think this parameter is the cause of disconnections.)

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000 (Name makes sense but value is too high)



Didn't you answer your own question?  What is insufficient about "tcp_keepalives_idle"?  I think any answer beyond that is going to have be found on the client side, or on a network device between the client and the server.

@jjanes, I figured out a workaround for my probem, But I am not sure what is the timeout which is causing the disconnection in the first place.

As @jjanes says, you answered your question. If tcp_keepalives_idle works, it is not the postgres server closing the connection, because this works at a lower level. What is "closing" the connection might be in the local kernel, or it could be in the network. Do you connect over a physical network or on localhost?

@hobgoblin, Yes, this is a tcp connection.
I posted this question hoping to figure out what could be closing the connection or in what direction I should continue my investigation. (If anyone else has faced similar issues)
